# What does the !! operator / notation stand for in R?

Tags: r, operators, tidyverse

I was reading a question in SO and came up with the !! operator. Ive been working with R for some time and never have seen it. First, Ive search for questions about it, and couldnt find one in SO (so this may be a duplicate). Also, go back to diferent R operators post and pages, and no one says anything of it.

In the question, the !! preceded an R oject, like:

```
> !!object
```

Thanks for the help.

P.D.: If its a duplicate, please close.

Comment: See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: tidyverse !! bang bang "unqoute" --- I think these are the keywords

Comment: It's not a real operator, it's treated as such by functions which can understand it, otherwise it means "not not", which is more or less equivalent to `as.logical`. These functions which can understand it are mainly found in the `tidyverse` packages

Comment: `?backtick!!backtick` should bring up detailed documentation.

Comment: `!!` is just doing `!` twice. `!` seeks for `FALSE`. Thus, `!FALSE == TRUE` and `!!FALSE ==FALSE`

Comment: @NelsonGon For operators it's sometimes easier for beginners to get to the help via `help("!!")` rather than dealing with backticks.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.2.2/topics/quasiquotation

Comment: Thanks you all for the comments. I will read the references you all gave me. Im very surprise if its meaning is the negation of a negation. Really cant think right now where that could fit. But it surely must have a use. Thanks again.